# While looping an array of objects in Svelte, how can I display the iteration count?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-2

I am iterating a JSON with the help of Svelte's `onMount` method. I have displayed the data in a table.

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from "svelte";

    const apiURL = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Goles/3196253/raw/9ca4e7e62ea5ad935bb3580dc0a07d9df033b451/CountryCodes.json";        
    let countries = [];
    
    onMount(async function() {
       const response = await fetch(apiURL);
       countries = await response.json();
    });

</script>

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Code</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {#if countries}
     {#each countries as country }  
     <tr>
      <td>{index + 1}</td>
      <td>{country.name}</td>
      <td>{country.code}</td>
     </tr>
     {/each}
    {:else}
    <p>There are no countries</p>
    {/if}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What I have not been able to do is add an iteration count column. Using `{index + 1}`.

How do I get the desired result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Index is a second argument of the `each` loop in svelte

```
{#each countries as country, index }  
  <tr>
  <td>{index + 1}</td>
  <td>{country.name}</td>
  <td>{country.code}</td>
  </tr>
{/each}
```

Here is the [docs link](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/each-blocks)